# DB2 Drop table if exists equivalent

Tags: sql, db2, sql-drop

I need to drop a DB2 table if it exists, or drop and ignore errors.

Comment: What context are you running this in?  If you're executing a script, the necessary abilities _may_ not be available.  If you're doing this from a higher level/application (RPG, Java, C#, etc), this is usually trivial.

Comment: See if this helps: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/509144-drop-table-view-only-if-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First query if the table exists, like

```
select tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema='myschema' and tabname='mytable'
```

and if it returns something issue your

```
drop table myschema.mytable
```

Other possibility is to just issue the drop command and catch the Exception that will be raised if the table does not exist. Just put that code inside try {...} catch (Exception e) { // Ignore } block for that approach.

Comment: The try/catch isn't good becasue the exception might be not due to table's absence, but due to the fact some constraints are referencing this table and it cannot be dropped until those constraints are dropped.

Comment: @mvmn: DB2 (at least the versions I know) always does a "cascading" drop. So any FK will silently be dropped anyway

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysibm.systables WHERE name = 'tab_name') THEN
DROP TABLE tab_name;END IF;
```

Comment: You should consider the schema name also, otherwise, the table name might exist in another schema, but not in yours, and exception will be thrown.

Comment: And you may also want to check that it's a table (and not a view).

Comment: DB2 does not support this kind of programmatic flow control

Comment: Like user1195888 said, this answer is misleading because it doesn't work on DB2 as was asked.

Answer (score 5):

The below worked for me in DB2 which queries the `SYSCAT.TABLES` view to check if the table exists. If yes, it prepares and executes the `DROP TABLE` statement.

```
BEGIN    
   IF EXISTS (SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND TABNAME = 'TABLE_NAME') THEN 
      PREPARE stmt FROM 'DROP TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME';
      EXECUTE stmt;
   END IF;                                                        
END
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in a Spring Boot initialization script (schema.sql), because Spring Boot will truncate this statement by the first semicolon. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32903696/8707976) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

search on systable : if you are on as400 (power i, system i) the system table name is QSYS2.SYSTABLES else try  sysibm.systables  or syscat.tables (This depends on the operating system)

```
BEGIN    
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURLIBINUPPER' AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUTABLENAMEINUPPER') THEN           
  DROP TABLE YOURLIBINUPPER.YOUTABLENAMEINUPPER;                             
END IF;                                                        
END  ;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is simpler and works for me:

```
DROP TABLE SCHEMA.TEST IF EXISTS;
```

Comment: That syntax is only available for Db2-LUW versions 11.5 and higher. So if you try to use this syntax on older versions (i.e. on almost all currently installed Db2-LUW installations) then it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answers here, if you want to be ANSI compatible you could also use the queries bellow. It should work for IBM i and LUW:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MY_SCHEMA' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

then if any result is returned:

```sql
DROP TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE;
```